# Application doesn't seem to meet google workspace marketplace requirements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

We are trying to deploy our app to `Google workspace marketplace` but we are bumping into a problem and it's that our app is rejected by google (when we tried to add the google drive feature)
Although in our test deployment everything is working fine
we contacted google support and they said that the app is not being registered in the add-on Bar due to a manifest issue as following

Also Note that all data are filled in the https://console.cloud.google.com
regarding gmail and drive sdk
[image]

```
•   The App doesn’t meet the publishing review criteria on the following:
  1.    Integration selected is not shown when configuring the Deployment ID in Marketplace 
        SDK and therefore is not shown in the Sidebar once the App is installed.
        In general this issue is caused by a problem in the definition of the manifest file 
        where the host specifics are not defined correctly so the Google Workspace Add-on does 
        not identifies in which product it needs to open.
```

Following is the manifest file provided

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {},
  "webapp": {
   "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
   "access": "ANYONE"
},
 "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
 "oauthScopes": [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly"
 ],
"urlFetchWhitelist": [
  "https://api.atlassian.com/",
  "https://auth.atlassian.com/",
  "https://id.atlassian.com/",
  "https://*.atlassian.net/",
  "https://*.atlassian.com/",
  "https://googletojirabackend.azurewebsites.net/",
  "https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-myself/#api-rest-api-3-myself-get"
],
"runtimeVersion": "V8",
 "addOns": {
"common": {
  "name": "GTJ Jira Connector",
  "logoUrl": "https://infosysta-apps.com:444/jiraforgmail/icon/gtj.png",
  "useLocaleFromApp": true,
  "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
    "https://*.atlassian.net",
    "https://*.atlassian.com"
  ],
  "universalActions": [
    {
      "label": "Settings",
      "runFunction": "buildSettingsCard"
    }
  ]
},
"gmail": {
  "contextualTriggers": [
    {
      "unconditional": {},
      "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
    }
  ],
  "primaryColor": "#363dfc",
  "secondaryColor": "#4285F4"
},
"drive": {
  "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onDriveItemsSelected"
  },
  "homepageTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onHomepage"
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that when the Deployment ID was configured the 'Add on' option was selected?

Comment: @Sora We are facing the same problem. What did you do to solve this problem?